# Random Forest, text classification

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, sentiment-analysis, text-classification, ensemble-learning

How can I use words as feature to classify text using random forest algorithm for sentiment analysis? I'm using words as features, whereas random forest uses numbers, this is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Actually it is the other way around. Words are better for RFs. However, you could use a bag of words representation if you really want to have numbers, e.g., for SVMs

Comment: @CAFEBABE Can you explain it a little bit in detail, what do u mean by words are better for RF? 
since this is my first project into machine learning, it's getting a bit heavy.
Thanks

Comment: You basically define a matrix where the features are weather a word occurs or not. Maybe you can read https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-1-for-beginners-bag-of-words this might give you a nice introduction

Comment: @CAFEBABE I'll take a look. Thank you.

Comment: @CAFEBABE Solved my problem completely. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the text data and what are the outcomes?  Are they multiple labels or binomial

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use sckit-learn to facilitate you in solving it. You can look for tutorial at the website of sckit-learn tutorial [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/index.html). it will be very useful.

When working with text features you can use CountVectorizer or DictVectorizer. Take a look at feature extraction and especially section 4.1.3 [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction).

To facilitate you to know more, you can find an example [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html). It will useful for classifying text documents.

Answer (score 0):

you can use countvectorizer or tfidf in the pre processing section of the random forest pipeline.  post an excerpt of your data and I will demostrate